# How to select and print the lines of a file delimited by two identifiers

Tags: python, string, file, identifier

I have a large file full of data subsets, each with a unique identifier.

I want to be able to find the first line containing the identifier and print that line along with every line after that one until the next data subset is reached (that line will start with `<`). The data is structured as shown below.

```
<ID1|ID1_x
AAA
BBB
CCC
<ID2|ID2_x
DDD
EEE
FFF
<ID3|ID3_x
...
```

I would like to print:

```
<(ID2)
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

So far I have:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'ID2' in line:
           print(line)
           ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the code below:

```
found_id = False
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '<ID' in line:
            if '<ID2' in line:
                id_line_split = line.split('|')
                id_line = id_line_split[0][1:]
                print('<(' + str(id_line) + ')')
                found_id = True
            else:
                found_id = False
        else:
            if found_id == True:
                # remove carriage return and line feed
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                line = line.replace('\r','')
                print(line)
```

The execution of previous code in my system, with your `file.txt` produces this output:

```
<(ID2)
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

---

### Second question (from comment)

To select `ID2` and `ID23` (see questione in the comment of this answer), the program has been changed in this way:

````
found_id = False
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '<ID' in line:
            if ('<ID2' in line) or ('<ID23' in line):
                id_line_split = line.split('|')
                id_line = id_line_split[0][1:]
                print('<(' + str(id_line) + ')')
                found_id = True
            else:
                found_id = False
        else:
            if found_id == True:
                # remove carriage return and line feed
                line = line.replace('\n','')
                line = line.replace('\r','')
                print(line)```
````

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! The txt file has 100,000+ of these IDs and sometimes I need to pull out a few of them. I tried adding another loop to your code to accomplish this, but I am having trouble getting it to work

```
found_id = False
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for ID in ('ID2', 'ID23'):
        for line in f:
        ...
```
but this only returns the desired lines for ID2

Comment: I have modified the answer